# Runtime Trie data structure generation vs storing & reading to a file approach

Tags: javascript, json, jackson, hierarchical-data, trie

I am creating a `Trie` structure for every single word in the English dictionary. I wanna use this structure for games such as word search & scrabble type games but I don't know if its faster to generate the structure at runtime or if I should be figuring out a way to flatten this `Trie` structure into `JSON` or `XML` to be read into memory at runtime.

I don't know much about creating databases or storing data for later usage so any recommendations would be awesome - right now im looking at `Jackson` and `Java`. The ultimate goal is to port this application to `JavaScript` on my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can generate [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) structure and use it on your website without using `Java`, just with `JavaScript`. Simple `Trie` structure with two methods: `insert` and `search` could look like this in `JS`:

```
function Trie() {
    this.root = new TrieNode();
    this.insert = function(key) { 
        let length = key.length, next = this.root; 

        for (let level = 0; level < length; level++) { 
            let character = key.charAt(level); 
            if (next.children[character] == null) {
                next.children[character] = new TrieNode(); 
            }

            next = next.children[character]; 
        }
        next.endOfWord = true; 
    }
    this.search = function(key) { 
        let length = key.length, next = this.root; 

        for (let level = 0; level < length; level++) { 
            let character = key.charAt(level);

            if (next && next.children[character]) {
                next = next.children[character];
                continue;
            }
            return false;
        }

        return next && next.endOfWord;
    } 
}

function TrieNode() {
    this.children = {};
    this.endOfWord = false; 
}
```

Using above simple implementation you can create `Trie` instance and insert all words you want:

```
const trie = new Trie();
trie.insert("hello");
trie.insert("hi");
trie.insert("help");
trie.insert("helpful");
... more words
```

For example, using [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) you can:

- Read all required words from source file.
- For each word insert it into `trie` structure using `insert` method.
- generate `JSON` from object by: `JSON.stringify(trie)`.
- Save it to a file: `trie.js` which can be used later on you page.

Result `js` file for above words should look like:

```
{
   "root":{
      "children":{
         "h":{
            "children":{
               "e":{
                  "children":{
                     "l":{
                        "children":{
                           "l":{
                              "children":{
                                 "o":{
                                    "children":{
                                       
                                    },
                                    "endOfWord":true
                                 }
                              },
                              "endOfWord":false
                           },
                           "p":{
                              "children":{
                                 "f":{
                                    "children":{
                                       "u":{
                                          "children":{
                                             "l":{
                                                "children":{
                                                   
                                                },
                                                "endOfWord":true
                                             }
                                          },
                                          "endOfWord":false
                                       }
                                    },
                                    "endOfWord":false
                                 }
                              },
                              "endOfWord":true
                           }
                        },
                        "endOfWord":false
                     }
                  },
                  "endOfWord":false
               },
               "i":{
                  "children":{
                     
                  },
                  "endOfWord":true
               }
            },
            "endOfWord":false
         }
      },
      "endOfWord":false
   }
}
```

To make a valid `JS` file with a code you need to add: `const RAW_TRIE =`  string at the beginning, so our file looks like:

```
const RAW_TRIE = {
   "root":{
      "children":{
         "h":{
          ...
```

You created a raw `Trie` object which you can include to your page by adding this line to your `HTML` or template files:

```
<script src="www.your-domain.com/path/to/static/file/trie.js"></script>
```

Since this file is loaded you should have an access to `RAW_TRIE` object. You can set [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) to `Trie` and use search method:

```
const TRIE = Object.setPrototypeOf(RAW_TRIE, new Trie());
console.log("hello exists: " + TRIE.search("hello"));
console.log("hello1 does not exist: " + TRIE.search("hello1"));
```

This approach allows you to create on server side file with all words you need and client can download it and use as a regular static file.

> **Note**: above solution is an only one way how to do that and some (or all) steps can be improved or changed. It is not a final version
> which can be used without any changes on production. You can try to
> optimise it and make `trie.js` file as small as possible by changing
> `TrieNode` function or even removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could create a Trie by extending the native `Map` prototype:

```js
class TrieNode extends Map {
    add(word) {
        if (!word.length) return super.set("end", true);
        let child = this.get(word[0]);
        if (!child) this.set(word[0], child = new TrieNode);
        child.add(word.slice(1));
        return this; // optional: to allow chaining
    }
    has(word) {
        if (!word.length) return super.has("end");
        let child = this.get(word[0]);
        return !!child && child.has(word.slice(1));
    }
    * [Symbol.iterator]() {
        for (let [letter, child] of super.entries()) {
            if (letter === "end") yield ""
            else for (let word of child) yield letter + word;
        }
    }
}

// Demo
let trie = new TrieNode;
// Insert all words
for (let word of ["so", "some", "somebody", "someone", "something", "son"]) {
    trie.add(word);
}
// For a series of strings, check whether they are in the Trie
for (let word of Array.from("somethings", (_, i) => "somethings".slice(0, i))) {
    console.log(`"${word}" => ${trie.has(word)}`);
}
// List all words that are in the Trie
for (let word of trie) console.log(word);
```